# Chrome Dev Console no longer allows to copy console logged text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

**Before**: I right click on the logged text and can select `Copy` to copy the logged texts.

**Now**: I right click on the logged text but no longer see any `Copy` option. I now only see the three options shown on the right side of the red box.

[image]

- Env

  - Chrome version: Version 119.0.6045.123 (Official Build) (arm64)
  - OS: macOS Ventura.13.5.2
- `Save as` allows to get the wanted texts but its too many extra steps.
- **Question:** Is there any setting/workaround that would allow to directly copy console logged texts again?

---

**Update:** As of Version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (arm64) - Text highlighting has been improved.

Comment: It does for me, you just have tro try harder and do it multiple times by selecting the text, it doesn't work that well, the fact that it highlights the current row doesn't mean that you have selected the text. It's just bad UI.

Comment: This appears to be a Mac/Chrome issue. It's working fine in latest Chrome on Windows

Comment: Works for me: Version 119.0.6045.106 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: It's a bug in this version of Chrome and AFAIK it's already fixed in the next version.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me as long as you highlight the text.

[image]

Comment: Note that the OP is using a macOS, not Windows. Also 'it works for me' is never an answer. There's always an underlying issue which we probably would need to tease more detail out of the OP.

Comment: This should be a comment. No picture is needed. Really, the question should just be closed.

Comment: Fair enough, but this is not a "it works for me" post - I am showing the same issue as the question asker on the first and second clicks, but then it works as expected once the text is highlighted. It's more of a "you're doing it wrong" post

Comment: It is bad UI as what @MarcoBonelli said. Does indeed work after manually selecting the text but the visibility of this manual selection is overwhelmed by the row highlighting.

Comment: Double-clicking selects a word, but have to drag to select the rest of the text.  And the selection is not visible.  Linux Chrome here.  It seems to have been broken recently